# update_attributes inside each rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, each

I have array of data

```
array = [1,2,4,6]
```

and what i want it update my model like this

```
array.each do |a|
  Mymodel.all.each do |mm|
    mm.update_attributes(name: a)
  end
end
```

but problem is when im trying to do this

`update_attributes` only with last `a`

at the end all objects have name  6

How can fix it?

Comment: What do you want as a result instead?

Comment: Could you be more specific about the problem? You're iterating over an array of numbers and setting the current number to the name attribute for all the models every time. The last number is 6 so at the end, all name attributes should contain 6.

Comment: Also, the code is incredibly ineffective. You might want consider using `update_all` for mass updates.

Answer (score 1):

because thats what you are doing, you are running each loop over the array but you are doing the same.

first iteration:

```
Mymodel.all.each do |mm|
  mm.update_attributes(name: 1)
end
```

second iteration:

```
Mymodel.all.each do |mm|
  mm.update_attributes(name: 2)
end
```

last iteration:

```
Mymodel.all.each do |mm|
  mm.update_attributes(name: 6)
end
```

so you just update every time the attribute `name` to the element in the array. and the last one is there to keep.

your logic is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

That's logical. For every element in the array you're updating all the model records. So first you're updating all your model entries with the first value in your array, being 1, then you're doing the same for very every model entry only with the value 2. Last value in your array is 6 so you're setting all the values in your model to `name` with the value 6.

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish but from your question I assume you want to update your model in order of your array. So something like this.

```
model_entries = Mymodel.all
array.each do |value, index|
    model_entries[index].update_attributes(name: value)
end
```

That's one solution, but it seems to me that's something wrong with your base logic here. From where I stand this is certainly something you want to solve in a different way. I can't really go into detail here as I don't know enough about what it is you're trying to achieve

Comment: Don't really get why this got a down vote. Basically saying the same as the up vote answer and I'm supplying an example of how he could do what he wants. With the side note that at the basis his logic is wrong